# php need to get output from multiple foreach in to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a newb at this so please bear with me. 
I'm trying to capture some data so i can count the unique value. There are 2 Separate sources for the data, there are 3 pieces of data i want to combine.  i can bring them together and echo them out but I cant get them in to an array so I can use array_count_values.

this is the code i have which echos the list out

```
<?php
foreach ($memberattacks2 as $memberb) {
    echo $memberb["Level"];

    foreach ($memberattacks as $memberf) {
        if ($memberf["tag"] == $memberb["ks"][1]["dTag"]) {
            echo $memberf["Level"];
        }
    }

    echo $memberb["ks"][1]["pins"];
}
```

this outputs a list of the numbers i can also output this to an html table, there will be about 15 unique variations of the combination of the 3 elements and i want to be able to count how many times each variation exists.

Comment: Is there a reason you are opening and closing php tags all over the place?

Comment: I'm a newb at this and trying to put together something from picking up bits of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an array, say `$combined`, and add your values into it like this:

```
$combined = array();

foreach ($memberattacks2 as $memberb) {

    $value = $memberb["Level"];
    echo $memberb["Level"];

    foreach ($memberattacks as $memberf) {
        if ($memberf["tag"] == $memberb["ks"][1]["dTag"]) {

            $value .= $memberf["Level"];
            echo $memberf["Level"];
        }
    }

    $value .= $memberb["ks"][1]["pins"];
    echo $memberb["ks"][1]["pins"];

    $combined[] = $value;
}
```

Then you can do `array_count_values()` on it:

```
$counted = array_count_values($combined);

var_export($counted);
```

Comment: Thank you for a great response, This seems to give a count of the unique values of each bit, what i was hoping to do is create a single value from the 3 bits of data and get a count across that. if that makes sense.

Comment: so the output of the first bit of dat would be a 9, the second could also be 9 and the 3rd could be a 3. I'd like to add them in to 1 string i guess you would say and count the number of times the combined sting appears.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it, please

Comment: Thank you so much Joe Black. This is perfect exactly what I was after. I've been trying to find something like this for a couple of days, you've saved me so much more searching.